# CondaHTTPError: HTTP 404 NOT FOUND for dask-core-2.7.0-py_0.tar.bz2

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda, http-error

I'm trying to clone an environment

```
conda create -n myenv_legacy --clone myenv
```

I'm getting the below error

```
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 404 NOT FOUND for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch/dask-core-2.7.0-py_0.tar.bz2>
```

The url `https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch/dask-core-2.7.0-py_0.tar.bz2` doesn't exist. However `dask-core-2.7.0-py_1.tar.bz2` (**py_1**, not py_0) exists.
How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure its the same problem, yet I have a very similar issue when installing a legacy library I wrote that used to work and when I wrote

```
conda install inspyred -c jacob-barhak
```

I got the following error

```
Downloading and Extracting Packages
inspyred-1.0         | 78 KB     |                                                                              |   0%

CondaMultiError: CondaHTTPError: HTTP 404 NOT FOUND for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/jacob-barhak/win-64/win-64\inspyred-1.0-py27_0.tar.bz2>
Elapsed: 00:00.423906
CF-RAY: 74c04c37b9b174a1-LHR

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
```

I talked to Ilan Schnell who was the main developer of conda in the past and the solution we ended up with was to build and upload the package to the anaconda cloud and delete the old package - this solved the problem for me.

The commands that solved my problem were:

```
conda build  <your package build file>
anaconda login   <enter your anaconda cloud credentials afterwards>
anaconda upload < the path of the package created - follow the build output>
```

Then login to the anaconda cloud and manually remove the old package

Hopefully this procedure will resolve similar issues - yet there is no guarantee that is is the same problem and this solution fits - so be careful and backup things.